# Adding ssh on embedded linux

Tags: compiling, software-installation, embedded, arm

I want to run SSH on Qtopia (on my FriendlyARM). My own distribution is Ubuntu, so I cannot copy and paste the ssh binary file into the device.

If I can copy and paste a binary file, where can I find it? If I must compile SSH, how is it possible in my ubuntu?

Comment: Doesn't Qtopia include SSH already? Its descendant Openmoko does.

Comment: nope! Although my Qtopia is pretty old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device has an [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM) processor. Your PC has an [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) processor. ARM and x86 are different processor architectures with different [instruction sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture). An executable program [compiled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) for x86 consists of x86 instructions that an ARM processor cannot execute, and vice versa.

You need an ARM binary. Furthermore, you need an ARM binary that's compatible with the other software you have on your device. Specifically, you need either a [statically linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_build) binary (a binary that does not depend on anything else) or a binary linked with the right system [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29).

Check which standard library you have. If you have a file called `/lib/ld-uClibc.so`, you have [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/), a small library intended for embedded systems. If you have a file called `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, you have [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc), the same library that you have on your Ubuntu PC (and any other non-embedded Linux).

You have two choices of SSH clients and servers: [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/) and [Dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html). Dropbear is smaller, but has fewer features, in particular no SFTP.

If the standard library is Glibc, you can grab a binary from Debian's ARM distribution. Get the `armel` [client](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/openssh-client) or [server](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/openssh-server) package. Extract the `.deb` file by running

```
dpkg-deb -x openssh-….deb .
```

Then copy the binary from `./usr/bin` or `./usr/sbin` to the device.

If the standard library is uClibc, you'll need to grab a binary from a distribution based on uClibc. [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) is included in many embedded distribution. [Openmoko](http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Main_Page), which shares some ancestry with Qtopia, includes Dropbear in its default installation. If you're going to want to install several programs, [BuildRoot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) makes it very easy to obtain a [cross-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-compiler) and build common programs: you pretty much only need to [follow the guide](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html).

Comment: Thank you Gilles. Dropbear solved my problem. I was trying to compile the SSH server for ARM but I found that I must build all of the dependencies and stuff which will be boring! although I found telnet more useful for my case and faster, and I can use FTP in command line to transfer files.